# Why can't I use `onWithOptions` in elm 0.19

Tags: elm

I am attempting to upgrade an elm application from 0.18 to 0.19.

I am stuck with this error -

```
Detected errors in 1 module.                                         
-- BAD IMPORT ---------------------------------------- src/Views/Interaction.elm

The `Html.Events` module does not expose `onWithOptions`:

13| import Html.Events exposing (onWithOptions)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
These names seem close though:

    onMouseEnter
    onMouseLeave
    onMouseOut
    onMouseOver
```

The [documentation](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html-Events#onWithOptions) shows that `onWithOptions` should be available.

My code is

```
module Views.Interaction exposing (onClickNoBubble)

{-| Helper functions for page interactions.


# Helpers

@docs onClickNoBubble

-}

import Html
import Html.Events exposing (onWithOptions)
import Json.Decode as Decode


{-| Replicates the onClick function but prevents bubbling
-}
onClickNoBubble : msg -> Html.Attribute msg
onClickNoBubble message =
    onWithOptions "click" { stopPropagation = True, preventDefault = True } (Decode.succeed message)
```

How do I move forward?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Elm 0.19 does not use `elm-lang/html`. You're reading the wrong documentation. It has been replaced by [`elm/html`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/1.0.0/) which has a [`custom`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/1.0.0/Html-Events#custom) function that serves the same purpose:

```
onClickNoBubble : msg -> Html.Attribute msg
onClickNoBubble message =
    Html.Events.custom "click" (Decode.succeed { message = message, stopPropagation = True, preventDefault = True })
```

Comment: This works if it is within an element that is not an `a`. As an `a` attribute, the Browser.application onUrlRequest acts before I can prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

I made a little helper function to get this to work.

```
onCustomClick : msg -> Html.Attribute msg
onCustomClick msg =
    custom "click"
        (Decode.succeed
            { message = msg
            , stopPropagation = True
            , preventDefault = True
            }
        )
```